# DataGrid Android Studio horizontal vertical scroll

Tags: android, android-studio, datagrid

I am looking for solution where could dispay large data with horizontal and vetical scroll. Something like this https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/new-datagrid-for-xamarinios-and-xamarinandroid.aspx. I would like to change number of columns and change the cell values.

Do you have please something like this? When it be a free i will be really happy. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can create it by custom `TableLayout`. And the good news is you can add both side scrolling mechanism in `TableLayout`. You have to first set a `TableLayout` xml. For both side scrolling you have to add first `ScrollView` then `HorizontalScrlollView` then your `TableLayout`.

Now you you can create **row** and **column**. You can create it dynamically because you (may be) dont know how many column has required. So you have to create custom TableRow and cell and you can easily add your `tableLayout` .

```
TableRow row= new TableRow(this);
        TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        row.setLayoutParams(lp);
// then create your text view and add it row. and last add row in your table layout
```

This is just example. You can create your own data grid library

And you can some ready mate library to show data grid in table view like your reference. :

https://github.com/evrencoskun/TableView
https://github.com/ISchwarz23/SortableTableView